# System.NullReferenceException in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have written the following line of code to check whether or not user enters password in the SettingViewController. I am testing with the following code, before user navigate to settingViewController page.However, I am getting SystemNullReference Error.

```
SettingViewController callSetting = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("SettingViewController") as SettingViewController;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callSetting.sSettings.password)==true) 
            Console.WriteLine("is null or empty");
        else 
            Console.WriteLine (callSetting.sSettings.password);
```

Here is my ServerSettings Class:

```
public class ServerSettings
{

    public string server{ get; set;}
    public string port { get; set;}
    public string username { get; set;}
    public string password { get; set;}
    public string userid { get; set;}

    public ServerSettings ()
    {

    }

}
```

Here is my SettingViewController class:

```
partial class SettingViewController : UIViewController
    {
    public ServerSettings sSettings;
    public SettingViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.Title = "Settings";

    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        sSettings.server=serverTF.Text;
        sSettings.port = portTF.Text;
        sSettings.password = passwordTF.Text;
        sSettings.userid = inboxuserTF.Text;
        sSettings.username = usernameTF.Text;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Either `callSetting` or `sSettings` is null.  You can't use a property off a null object.

Comment: @Amy, how should I to handle it?

Comment: I don't believe that simply instantiating a ViewController automatically creates instances of all it's controls.  If you've just create a new VC and have not shown it to the user why would any of it's fields have data?

Comment: it does not have data, however, once user enters the data (username, pwd, etc..) and then I will parse this data with the service URL. That is why I am checking to see whether or not I am getting user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, there's two different possibilities.

A) `callSetting` is `null`

B) `callSetting.sSettings` is `null`.

You could add something like this:

```
SettingViewController callSetting = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("SettingViewController") as SettingViewController;

 if (callSetting == null)
   throw new Exception("callSetting is null"); // Or if you can handle having a null callSetting then correct for it, but realistically this is a problem, so I'd throw an Exception

 if (callSetting.sSetting == null)
   throw new Exception("sSetting is null"); // Or if you can handle having a null callSetting.sSetting then correct it (such as using a default value).

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callSetting.sSettings.password)==true) 
    Console.WriteLine("is null or empty");
 else 
    Console.WriteLine (callSetting.sSettings.password);
```

Also as a side note, you could simplify this line

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callSetting.sSettings.password)==true)
```

to

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callSetting.sSettings.password))
```

Edit: Based on the edited question, you'll need to modify your code to this

```
public SettingViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    this.Title = "Settings";
    this.sSettings = new ServerSettings();
}
```

Comment: throw new Exception("sSetting is null"); // Or if you can handle having a null callSetting.sSetting then correct it (such as using a default value).
this part throws an exception

Comment: How could I enable my code to run even though my object is null ?

Comment: Of course it does. That's what's it's supposed to do. Can you handle having a null `sSettings` object? If you can, you can wrap it with an `if`-statement.

Comment: you are declaring sSettings, but you never instantiate (new) it.  You should instantiate a new copy in your constructor, otherwise it will always be null.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Now I have got it.

Comment: Any idea for the following question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509888/pass-data-from-oneviewcontroller-to-anotherviewcontroller-in-xamarin