# UserDefault in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to assign textfield entries just right before SettingViewController dismissed, and checking them while URLViewController appears.

However, once I check it returns null even though user entered all required information;

//SettingViewController

```
partial class SettingViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ServerSettings sSettings;
        public SettingViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.Title = "Settings";
            this.sSettings = new ServerSettings();

        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            sSettings.server=serverTF.Text;
            sSettings.port = portTF.Text;
            sSettings.password = passwordTF.Text;
            sSettings.userid = inboxuserTF.Text;
            sSettings.username = usernameTF.Text;
        }
    }
```

//URLViewController

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        SettingViewController callSetting = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("SettingViewController") as SettingViewController;

        if (callSetting == null)
            throw new Exception("callSetting is null"); // Or if you can handle having a null callSetting then correct for it, but realistically this is a problem, so I'd throw an Exception

        if (callSetting.sSettings == null)
            throw new Exception("sSetting is null"); // Or if you can handle having a null callSetting.sSetting then correct it (such as using a default value).

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callSetting.sSettings.password)==true) 
            Console.WriteLine("is null or empty");
        else 
            Console.WriteLine (callSetting.sSettings.password);

    }
```

Even though user fullfill all the textfield entries, it returns null.
//SettingsViewController
[image]

//URLViewController
[image]

Comment: There's no way we can help you with this. This is an application design concern. You may want to talk with someone else who works on this application or your architect for advice.

Comment: You are not waiting for the ViewController to get dismissed, you are checking the values immediately after you create it.  The code in ViewWillAppear continues to run after your UrlViewController is created.

Comment: Have you considered that your password field is blanked out because it's a password?  You might need to use a special accessor to access it.  We really can't help you with the amount of code you've given

Comment: No, I enter the password textfield, and then click on go back button and try to write it on console.writeline

Comment: @Jason, what would be your suggestion to fix? I am trying to assign textfield entries just right before SettingViewController dismissed, and checking them while URLViewCntroller appears. I think the logic should be fine, but the output contradicts me. I am confused.

Comment: @Jason, I have illustrated with couple of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the problem by using dictionary& userdefaults as follows:

In the B Viewcontroller, keep the user entries in the dictionary, map it and assign it to the userdefault.

```
partial class BViewController : UIViewController
{
    const string server = "server";
    const string port = "port";
    const string password = "password";
    const string username = "username";
    const string inboxuserid = "inboxuserid";
    .............
    .............



  public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
  {
    var appDefaults = new NSDictionary (server, serverTF.Text, port, portTF.Text, password, passwordTF.Text,username,usernameTF.Text, inboxuserid,inboxuserTF.Text);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults (appDefaults);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize ();
  }

}
```

and retrieve them in the A ViewController as follows:

```
partial class AViewController : UIViewController
 {



  public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
   {
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults (appDefaults);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize ();
    var username = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey ("username");
    Console.WriteLine (username);
    }
}
```

There are also good examples in the following links:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/AppPrefs/Settings.cs
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9089/nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults-returns-null-first-time